# Connecting from Azure App Service to Azure SQL using User-assigned Managed Identity

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect my App Service to Azure SQL using user-assigned managed identity.

Here is what I've done so far:

1. Created the user-assigned managed identity
2. Assigned it to the App Service
3. Added the user to the SQL and assigned it a role
4. Added an app setting named `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` with the client id of the identity
5. In the connection string, added the `Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;User ID=<client id of the identity>;`

It's important to note that I have also a VM in Azure using the very same code, and there it works flawlessly.

However, with the app service, I keep getting the following error:

`Received a non-retryable error. Identity Response Code: BadRequest, Response: {"statusCode":400,"message":"No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId."}`

Note that with system-assigned managed identity it works without any problem.

What am I missing? How can I make it work?

Comment: I set up a connected service under a container app for an azure sql instance using the Azure portal and CLI and then the connection worked. But I haven't figured out what it changed so I haven't been able to recreate using bicep deployment.